# dump($request); does not work in this code. Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.6

The code does not have any syntax error, but does not work. It seems the code has no interaction with database.

```
public function execute(Request $request) {

        if($request->isMethod('post')) {

            $messages = [
                'required' => "Campo :attribute rellenado",
                'email' => "Este :attribute campo debe rellenarse con su email"
            ];

            $this->validate($request,[

                'name' => 'required|max:255',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'text' => 'required'
            ], $messages);

            dump($request);
```

Comment: "Does not work" is not a good explanation of the bug....

Answer (score 0):

edit your rules

```
    $messages = [
        'name.required' => 'This Field Name is required ',
        'name.max' => 'The name should be :max in length',
        'email.required' => 'the email field is required',
        'email.email' => 'the email  should be valid email',
        'text.required' => 'the the text is required',
    ];

    $this->validate($request,[

        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'text' => 'required'
    ], $messages);
```

the `dump($requset)` will not work in this case because you are using request trait where `$this->validate` function automatically redirect back if validation fails

Comment: Can you highlight the differences and explain why they are neccessary?

Comment: the base controller using `ValidatesRequests` trait who perform redirect if validation fails

Answer (score -1):

Try to change `dump($request)` to `dd($request)`

```
if($request->isMethod('post')) {

            $messages = [
                'required' => "Campo :attribute rellenado",
                'email' => "Este :attribute campo debe rellenarse con su email"
            ];

            $this->validate($request,[

                'name' => 'required|max:255',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'text' => 'required'
            ], $messages);

            dd($request);
```

Comment: Can you explain why `dump` is the wrong method to call here?